# mootool set value to div

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am using Mootools and I have the following div:

```
<div class="total-title">12</div>
```

I want to change this div text but my code is not working:

```
$('total-title').set('text', 'text goes here');
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged with "jquery" if it's a mootools question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given your div a class, no an ID, so the following:

```
$$('.total-title').set('text', 'text goes here');
```

Comment: Its a little different from jQuery. The $() function only supports finding elements by ID. You have to use the $$() function to find elements by CSS selectors. Once you get that through your brain, mootools is great to use.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that for a  element you want to set the "html" property, not the "text" property.